TypeError: client.initIndex is not a function (algolia, firebase functions)
import { logger } from "firebase-functions";
import { algoliasearch } from "algoliasearch";
import { onRequest } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import {
  onDocumentCreated,
  onDocumentUpdated,
} from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

initializeApp();

// algolia config
const appID = 
const apiKey = 

const client = algoliasearch(appID, apiKey);
const index = client.initIndex('task_list')


export const updateTaskList = onDocumentUpdated(
  "new_users/{id}",
  async (event) => {
    const beforeUpdate = event.data.before.data();
    const afterUpdate = event.data.after.data();

    try{
      index.partialUpdateObjects(afterUpdate).then(({ id }) => {
        logger.log(id)
      });
    } catch(error) {

    }


    return null;
  }
);

All the blog post about updating the index seems to be using this initialisation only, but it's not working for me.
Also if I want to specify an attribute for unique identifier can I do that?
Suppose a field named 'id' exists in the records that I've manually uploaded as json and now I want to update them by comparing the 'id' from my firestore object.
